# Airship setUserNotificationsEnabled malfunction on Android with Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I am using Airship in Flutter for my iOS and Android Apps. According to [Airship Documentation for Flutter](https://docs.airship.com/platform/mobile/push/getting-started/?groupid=flutter)
setting `Airship.setUserNotificationsEnabled(true)` should show a prompt so user can decide if they want push notifications or not. It happens both on iOS and on Android with that difference that Android always sets it to `true`.

Precisely, if I do

```
Airship.setUserNotificationsEnabled(true).then((status) => {

 // status here is always 'true' on Android
 // if I open App settings, it is correctly false
 // but I need to implement some features that relying on the status variable
 // in iOS, the status is always correct, so it can be 'true' or 'false' according to users choice

}
```

What could be the reason for the bahavior?

Airship: `^6.3.2`

Flutter `3.10.5`

Answer (score 0):

Should be fixed in Flutter 7.0.0.